# Can't upgrade Reminders anywhere

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, reminders

Last year (2021) I upgraded the OS on my mac and got the "Where are my Reminders?" note, and message about needing to upgrade them to access them.  I did that, and they have been unavailable ever since.

On my phone (running latest iOS 14) I still get the "Where are my Reminders?" and "The creator of this list has upgraded these Reminders" messages.

On my mac (Running Catalina), I also get those same two message.

At iCloud.com *I also get these same two messages!*

I have disabled/enabled messages on both my phone and mac, no change.

It's been over a year and I've basically accepted that these Reminders are forever gone (which REALLY SUCKS btw), but today I saw the messages again and decided to do some more sleuthing, but have gotten nowhere.

Does anyone have any idea how to actually get these things to upgrade and get them back?  Apple claims "You can always see your Reminders on a Mac or PC by signing into iCloud.com with a compatible web browser," but this is utter BS as I have never been able to access these lost Reminders at icloud.com.  Incredibly frustrating and disappointing to lose data like this.  Holding out hope that there is some way to recover them.